# Serializing a `tf.Summary` object to `string` Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I try to generate image summaries to be displayed in tensorboard. This worked in an eager execution environment.

Now, I try to use the `eval_metric_ops` returning a dict of operations to compute metrics during execution of the computation graph. For this, I rely on `tf.py_func` to do my metrics computations and plots. This function signature is

```
tf.py_func(
    func,
    inp,
    Tout,
    stateful=True,
    name=None
)
```

Where `Tout` is the returned type of the function. I managed to make it work for simple metrics (float values). As far as I understand, I need to define a `string` returned type for my summaries which will be parsed after to *rebuild* my images.

**Here is the blocking point.**

I build my Summary with:

```
summ = tf.Summary(value=[
  tf.Summary.Value(
    tag=metric_name,
    image=tf.Summary.Image(
       encoded_image_string=encode_image_array_as_png_str(
         self._last_metrics[metric_name])))])
```

Returning it as is, I get: `W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1306] Unimplemented: Unsupported object type Summary`

Returning `str(summ)` gives: `WARNING:tensorflow:Skipping summary for ..., cannot parse string to Summary`.

I also tried to build it with:

```
tf.summary.image(
    name,
    tensor,
    max_outputs=3,
    collections=None,
    family=None
)
```

But this gives: `W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1306] Unimplemented: Unsupported object type Tensor`

---

Do you know how to serialize a Summary to a string/bytes iterable/whatever can be interpreted as a string Tensor, in a way that it can be parsed back to an image Summary after that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shame on me.

As many other classes in tensorflow, Summary is defined by a Protocol Buffer message and thus, implement the [`SerializeToString()`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial#parsing-and-serialization).
Hence, just returning `summ.SerializeToString()` works!